# Is it frowned upon to mention specific clients in a CV?

Tags: resume, career-switch

Now, I've always thought (probably through misinformation) that it was bad practice to mention actual client names when writing your CV, is this true?

I am currently rewriting my CV and I'd like to mention client projects I've worked on, as some of them are household names and I feel would emphasise the level of work that I've been involved with.

My profession is software development, not sure whether that would be of any relevance though.

Comment: From my experience this varies per company.  It may also be in your contract that you are not allowed to mention any of the companies clients.  However, there are ways to "get around" this.  One way is to mention that you work with several Fortune 100, 200, 250 clients.  Speak of the size and maybe even how much money the clients are projected to be worth, without giving out their name of course.  I agree with you though, when working with reputable clients, you want the world to know about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Legal Obligations

Before mentioning any client by name, you need to make sure that your contract with that company does not forbid you from mentioning the client's name.

### Ethical Obligations

Would you feel comfortable asking the company to allow you to use their name on a website promoting your services? If you did ask, would they be likely to accept? Even if you are legally allowed, it would be unethical to do it in a method they aren't as likely to discover if you wouldn't feel comfortable doing it on the up-and-up.

If you're in doubt, ask first, because...

### Practical Obligations

What if your potential employer/client actually contacts this company? Will they get upset? Will they endorse you? Because if you put the name down and the company is upset about it, it will hurt your chances in the long run.

### In Summary

Check your contract and then ask the client. If they say it's okay, feel free to put it in if you think it will help your chances. If not, you can use the roundabout ways mentioned by Eric Sanders in the comments, such as, "Fortune 100 company" or whatnot rather than the client name.

Answer (score 8):

It's a matter of fact that you worked for them. Unless under a fairly severe NDA, you can mention it if it's relevant.

If you want to actually impress people, then something they've heard of ("I designed the global Playstation 1 launch campaign") is probably even more effective than ("In 1994 I designed the global launch campaign for a multi-billion-dollar-revenue product from a major multinational consumer electronics company"). It's also shorter, at risk of the reader not knowing that the Playstation 1 was a successful consumer electronics product (!)

Note: I have no idea whether Sony really used an external media consultancy to design that campaign. If not then no defamation intended ;-)

The main thing would be to avoid just name-dropping to no purpose. If you did some freelance leaflet design, nobody cares whether it was for Sony or Nintendo. It might feel like the experience is worth more than doing some leaflet design for Bob's Mom And Pop Store. And perhaps it is, since if nothing else you can use it as evidence you can work with "serious" branding guidelines. But that's equally served just by saying "for a multinational brand". Or better yet "for multinational brands", since doing it twice is better than a one-off.

Beware that the person reading your CV knows that even household names do a lot of skut-work. Saying you had Sony as a client isn't impressive. The contractor they got in to carpet a small office isn't any better a hiring prospect than the contractor Bob's Mom got in. Saying that you did something *that affected the overall fortunes of an organisation the size of Sony* is impressive, otherwise there's no point name-dropping.

Also note that showing discretion in your CV might be inherently valuable in certain lines of work, and naming clients would be crass. Roach exterminator, for example. By contrast, if you design websites then you're going to show a portfolio anyway, so if that allows the reader to identify clients then discretion isn't such an issue.

Specifically for software development: if you customized some Drupal modules for Sony's website then it probably doesn't matter all that much who your client was. AFAIK Sony isn't reknowned among software developers for the quality of the Drupal modules it uses on its websites. If they brought you in to architect the system software on the Playstation 4 then yeah, that's their core business, and will be noted by interviewers for the same reason you'd expect it to be noted if you'd done it as a permanent employee of Sony rather than them merely being a client. That said, any games developer who's had any trouble with the Playstation 4 could hold it against you ;-)