# Adding projects to résumé as a consultant

Tags: professionalism, resume, collaboration

Is it advised for a consultant to ask its customers the consent to list a selection of projects into his résumé? Specifically adding each one a little detail, such as:

- project name
- customer
- url (we're talking about web projects)
- timespan of online activity
- two screenshots

My concern is that the customer can deny its consent, though for reasons that elude any qualitative aspect of the work (would it be bad, one's would not be interested to show) or of the professional relationship (which AFAIK is very good on both sides). So, are there tolerated and less specific forms to list collaborations? I'm thinking about: "I had the honor to collaborate on projects for: <client1>, <client2>, <client3>, ..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what field you are in, for example if you are a psychologist is not allowed to share anything about other clients at all, but I think that in your work it is normal to want to build a portfolio of projects and to share it.

However I do think that it is almost always a good idea to ask permission. If you, as you say, have a good relationship with them I think they will most probably give you permission.

Also see [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/10636/is-it-frowned-upon-to-mention-specific-clients-in-a-cv) for more answers.

Answer (score 2):

That depends heavily on the kind of work you do and what you signed when accepting this project. If its a publicly visible project, like a website, most clients probably won't mind you mentioning it, and it would pose no problem to do so.

If the project is something more risky, like maybe a specialised app for the financial sector, or maybe something that shuffles patient data in the medical sector, then you may well not be allowed to mention specific details of the project. The same applies if you signed a NDA (non disclosure agreement).

For these kinds of work, you can simply list them in the form:

- Project: $Broad Work Type
- Duration: $Duration
- Client: $Client (wether or not you will be allowed to mention this differs based on legal obligations, so definitely consult a lawyer first if you're having doubts)